# Download an unknown file using basic authentication and compensating for redirects

Tags: .net, powershell, download, httpwebrequest

Seriously?  It can't be this much code to simply download a file.  Basic authentication and redirects seem like simple stuff.  After I got through this code, I sat back and thought there has got to be a simpler approach that I am overlooking.  I think there are even problems with this code (Doesn't compensate for all successful status codes, not robust on header parsing, etc.)

Edit: I need to know the file name supplied by the web server to save it locally as the same name.

Do I really have to keep adding code to this solution or am I overlooking a simpler approach?

```
Function DownloadFile ([String]$Source, [String]$Destination, [String]$Domain = $Null, [String]$User = $Null, [String]$Password = $Null)
{
    $Request = [System.Net.WebRequest]::Create($Source)

    If ($User)
    {
        $Credential = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($User, $Password, $Domain)

        $CCache = New-Object System.Net.CredentialCache
        $CCache.Add($Request.RequestURI, "Basic", $Credential)

        $Request.Credentials = $CCache
    }

    $Request.AllowAutoRedirect = $False
    $Response = $Request.GetResponse()
    Switch ([Int]$Response.StatusCode)
    {

        302
        {
            If ($Response.Headers['Content-Disposition'])
            {
                #attachment; filename=something.ext
                $FileName = $Response.Headers['Content-Disposition'].Split('=')[-1]
            }
            Else
            {
                #/foo/bar/something.ext
                $FileName = $Response.Headers['Location'].Split('/')[-1]
            }

            $Response.Close()
            $Location = New-Object System.URI($Request.RequestURI, $Response.Headers['Location'])
            DownloadFile ($Location) ($Destination + '\' + $FileName) $Domain $User $Password
        }

        200
        {
            $ResponseStream = $Response.GetResponseStream()
            $FileStream = New-Object System.IO.FileStream($Destination, [System.IO.FileMode]::Create)
            $Buffer = New-Object Byte[] 1024
            Do
            {
                $ReadLength = $ResponseStream.Read($Buffer, 0, 1024)
                $FileStream.Write($Buffer, 0, $ReadLength)
            } While ($ReadLength -ne 0)
            $FileStream.Close()
        }

        Default
        {
            $Response.Close()
            Throw "Unexpected HTTP Status Code $([Int]$Response.StatusCode)"
        }

    }

    $Response.Close()

}
```

Comment: Use Webclient.Download() ? it'll handle all for you. (AFAIK it support default credentials cache but I'm not really sure)

Comment: That was the simple solution I started with, but it didn't allow me to detect what the file name was being downloaded so I could save it as the same name locally.

Answer (score 0):

I use this function to download a file:

```
function download-file {
  param([string]$url, [string]$filePath, [string]$user, [string]$pass)
  if ($url -notmatch '^http://') {
    $url = "http://$url"
    write-host "Url corrected to $url"
  }
  $w = New-Object net.webclient
  if ($user) {
    write-debug "setting credentials, user name:  $user"
    $w.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($user,$pass)
  }
  $w.DownloadFile($url, $filePath)
}
```

It downloads the file and stores it to path `$filePath`. Example:

```
download-file 'http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/c3ba8d5e440f00f11c7df365a19342b4?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG' c:\tempfile.jpg
ii c:\tempfile.jpg
```

It should handle redirects, but throws exception when any unexpected error occures.

Comment: I started with something similar to this. However, the redirect is designed on the server side to download the latest file. I need to grab the file name provided by the web server to save my local file as the same. I couldn't figure out an easier way to do this short of parsing the inbetween redirect headers.

Also I got caught up on the basic authentication.  I only got it to work when I used the CredentialCache and clearly identified the credential for usage with "Basic".